# Smarty / How to include PHP function to compress CSS file

Tags: php, css, smarty

I do have a PHP function which pretty much compresses specific CSS files.

I recently added smarty to this project. Previously, this is what I had:

```
<link href="<?php echo $layoutParameter['routeCSS']; ?>global.css.php" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

In global.css.php I do have a function which sends back the "compressed" CSS content. For performance reasons and since the CSS files included in here were global settings it worked fine.

Now, with Smarty, I do create and extension plugin function and do something like this:

```
<link href="{compressed}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The result: all the CSS content is shown in the webpage, in other words, not linking the CSS, but rather including the return string from the PHP function.

Is there any way to accomplish this with Smarty?

I added each CSS to a new file and using that one for now, without PHP cleaning up spaces and comments.

Thanks,

Comment: Why are you compressing your css on each call of your page? This is a waste of resources. You should store its compressed version in a css file and statically load that one

Comment: @periklis I agree with you, thats what I am doing now. However, for my own knowledge, I am wondering how to accomplish the same with Smarty and the PHP function.

Comment: ok. To answer your question, what you where doing there, was to load the output of the compressed, not the url of a file. So your code was equivalent to `<link href = ".class1{foo;}.class2{bar}etc}"`, as if you had loaded all your css in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can assign data with

`$smarty->assign('layout', $layoutParameter);`

you can reach with

`<link href="{$layout['routeCss']}global.css.php" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

But I also don't recommend to compress css in php. It should be static

Comment: On the other hand, I agree with you, I will not rollback to the previous implementation, instead I will use the static approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is an awesome plugin called Smarty Combine, it combines and minify multiple JS and CSS, you can take a look at:

https://github.com/dead23angel/smarty-combine

Example (Smarty 3):

```
{combine input=array('/file1.js','/file2.js') output='/cache/big.js' age='30' debug=false}
```